# jQuery selector using on

Tags: jquery

```
$('#container').on('click', 'a',function()..
```

and

```
$('#container a').on('click',function()..
```

What is the difference between both selectors.

Comment: http://24ways.org/2011/your-jquery-now-with-less-suck  Look into the Event Delegation section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first will bind to all current and future anchor tags while the second will only bind to existing anchor tags.

the first is almost identical to using `.delegate()`, the only difference is the event and selector are swapped.

Edit: Answer to comment since it is rather long

The first is useful for dynamic content or content that contains a lot of anchor tags. The first only binds a single event that listens for events to bubble up to it that were triggered on elements that match the given selector. The first one could be re-written as `$("#container").delegate("a","click",function()...` for the exact same functionality. It is far more efficient in most cases than binding events directly to the elements. However, if your content is not dynamic and doesn't contain very many anchor tags, you should use the second piece of code because it is less complex than the first.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still a little confused. How is each useful is real life examples.

Comment: Added answer to comment to my answer

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I'm dealing with dynamic content. So first selector seems to be the answer. Is the first selector different from `$('#container').find('a').on('click',function()'..

Comment: The find will not work with dynamic content, so in your case the first would be the better one to use.

Answer (score 3):

1. Code snippet 1:

   Set a click event to all anchor tags that are or will be in `#container`
2. Code snippet 2:

   Set a click event to all anchor tags in `#container`

Answer (score 1):

The former attaches the click-handler to the `#container` element, which assigns an event if the click happens to be focused on an `a` element. This is particularly useful if the `a` elements might be updated, removed or added dynamically following assignment/binding of event-handlers.

The latter attaches the click handler directly to the `a` elements contained within the `#container` element. Which means those elements *must* be present in the DOM at the time the event-handlers and functions are bound to the nodes in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
selector
A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that
trigger the event. If the selector is null or omitted, the event is always
triggered when it reaches the selected element.
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the 'a' is a selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event. If the selector is null or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.